# We want to get rid of backup tapes - any suggestions

Tags: windows, backup

We have about 800GB to back up daily - any suggestions on best way to do it?

Comment: If you can elaborate on what you're backing up, what capacity tapes you're trying to move from, and maybe what your budget is, it would be pretty helpful.

Comment: Are you actually putting 800GB on tape daily, or do you have "800GB to back up" and use an incremental/differential scheme to only back up the parts that have changed?

Comment: are you deduplicating at all?

Comment: How quickly do you want to be back in business after a restore: a day, a week? And what data are you looking to restore? I find it more helpful to think of what I want to restore and how quickly I need it before I address the technology need, if that makes sense. Any other environment details you can provide would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest keeping the tape to cover mission critical data like your accounting.
For everything else you might look into a NAS/SAN solution for your regular backups and then an offsite vendor for archival information.

Comment: +1 Tape isn't dead, and probably won't ever be. The data has to be sent off site, and kept for ever and tape is still the most cost effective way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything more about your environment I would suggest that you look in to [Virtual Tape Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_tape_library) (VTL) solutions like the ones from [FalconStor](http://www.falconstor.com/products/virtual-tape-library).  These provide a lot of the benefits of a SAN for local backups, and also have the option of dumping your backups to a physical tape to be moved off-site (mission-critical data).

Similar systems can be home-grown with a SAN, a tape drive, and judicious use of tape-sized file volumes on the SAN (copy the volume to a tape if it needs to go off-site), but the commercial VTL vendors have been doing this for a while, and they're very good at it.